# HTML5 Page Loading Issues (using jQuery + JS + HTML5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My service pages have some loading/displaying issues.

I am using jQuery UI - Tabs for outer and inner tabs and a "footable" component to display table records. jQuery tabs & footable component are prepared in jQuery ready method.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
          $( "#tests" ).tabs();        
          $('.footable').footable(); 
           ....
      }
```

From some reason the page is displayed before the UI is well positioned and the page has some poor layout effects which looks very unprofessional.

Is there a problem with jQuery tabs which requires to initialize them in other way?
Appreciate any idea...

**Example: here is how the page looks before it is well positioned**

[image]

**here is how the page looks after it is well positioned**

[image]

Comment: Do you use ready before calling your jQuery ?

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem before using jquery tabs with other table plugins.

jQuery UI's tabs have an activate event that fires when you click a tab. You will need to call the footable's redraw() method inside that.

```
$('#tests').tabs({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
      $('.footable').data('footable').redraw();
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I misread footables api, I just edited it with what should work.

Comment: I have a feeling that the problem related to outer and inner jQuery Tabs

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,

In the container DIV which holds the tabs I place a style of display:none
And at the end of the jQuery ready function (after I prepare the tabs) I turn it on 
with a css display block.